# Crash when app enters foreground - because delegate = self?

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, crash

my app is occassionaly crashing when it enters the foreground. It doesn't always happen, but I think I've managed to isolate what is causing it. I am using this line:

```
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
```

Where self.locationManager is a retained property. When I comment this line out, the app can repeatedly come into the foreground and not crash.

I dont really understand what happens to viewcontrollers when they go into the background or come into the foreground.

Any ideas?

Comment: Paste the output of the console for the crash

Comment: Where is this line located? What method?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it now.

I added this line to the dealloc method of the viewcontroller:

```
self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
```

That seemed to sort it out....